# Export all comments from all post in facebook-graph-api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook page and i currently try to see how the overall people think about my FB page so I found out that the simple way to know that is using word clouds using python
so I try using FB graph API to export all post comment but it only gives me one post
like this

```
{186410560371****}/comments
```

is there a command to help me export all post comments from all my post at once

Comment: No, there is not. You will have to iterate the posts, and request the comments for each of them.

Comment: i have a question since im new in it can I do it inside python? for example I make a list of all facebook post id and go for each of them and insert it in dataframe ?